# Techniques for securing data on the client side

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, security

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app that requires some moderately heavy processing. In order to scale the app, I'm trying to offload the processing on the browser.  It's a game where the user has to answer a question.  The moderately heavy processing comes when the answer needs to be verified.  In order to verify the answer is correct, the client side needs to store the answer, or at least be able to request it from the server, but at some the client-side javascript needs compare the user's answer with the correct answer.  To prevent cheating, I need to secure the correct answer on the client-side?

**Things I've tried**

1. I tried hashing the answer data and embedding it in the HTML, but unfortunately I need access to the unhashed answer data since its value is used during the processing.
2. I tried using AJAX to request the answer data from the server, but I can use a number of tools to inspect the JSON response and view the answer data coming back.

**Thinks I haven't tried**

1. What if I used SSL encryption and requested the answer data whenever it was needed?  Wouldn't that prevent users from viewing the JSON data that is returned since it's encrypted?  Sorry if I'm totally off base with this, I'm new to web development and still learning.

Are there any other techniques for securing data on the client side with the technologies I'm using? Or any techniques for at least making it as difficult as possible for the user to view the answer data?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. If you need the unprocessed answer data to process the input, this data has to be on the client's machine, which means it's exposed.

Let me explain that in some pseudo-code:

```
func isValid(myAnswer, superSecureData)
    if decode(superSecureData) == myAnswer
        return true

    return false
```

An attacker would only have to do :

```
print decode(superSecureData)
```

Or, better even:

```
return true
```

Of course, this would be more secure :

```
func isValid(myAnswer, superSecureData)
    if encode(myAnswer) == superSecureData
        return true

    return false
```

But, as you said, you can't hash the answer, and as I already mentioned, an attacker could still force a function to simply `return true` (which is why you should do server-side checks on all supposedly valid answers).

Comment: +1 - The golden rule is that you cannot trust _anything_ the client says.

Comment: What about making it difficult then?  I was just reading up on someone approaching this same issue using compiled java applets. There's an example of software running on the client side that is difficult to break into. Your thoughts?

Comment: SSL encryption encrypts data between the client and the server, but both have full access to the data. And yes, it's possible to make it hard, but that's about all you can do.

Comment: Thanks, Tom! That makes sense. Do you have any suggestions for making it difficult?

Comment: Do the logic on the server, but optimize your internal logic as much as you can. If you're really afraid of scaling issues, try caching possible answers and doing all the logic on the front-end (so that your database server scales across multiple front-ends). That way you can scale horizontally.